# Docker not running in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am running a jenkins docker image by doing this:

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -u root \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /home/ec2-user/jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v "$HOME":/home \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I have my jenkins server up but when I try to run a docker build image as below:

```
pipeline {
    environment{
        registry = "leexha/node_demo"
        registyCredential = 'dockerhub'
        dockerImage = ''
    }

    agent any
    tools{
        nodejs "node"

    }
    stages {

        stage('Git clone'){
            steps{
                git 'https://github.com/leeadh/node-jenkins-app-example.git'
            }

        }
        stage('Installing Node') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }

        stage ('Conducting Unit test'){
            steps{
                sh 'npm test'
            }

        }

        stage ('Building image'){
            steps{
                script{
                    dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
                }
            }

        }


        stage ('Pushing to Docker Hub'){
            steps{
                script{
                    docker.withRegistry('',registyCredential){
                        dockerImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

it keeps telling me that dcoker is not found.

I already enabled the docker process to communicate via the  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \

So im pretty confused now whats going on.

ANy help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install docker on Jenkins Server (insider the Jenkins image container). And install and config Jenkins plugin: [docker](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) on your Jenkins Server.

Comment: HI yong, I did that as well. I enabled the docker plugin in my jenkins server. Still no luck